# gmake emits a "permission denied" error on a target. Why?

Tags: sass, makefile, gnu-make

I'm running a golang build under a Makefile, and getting a truly strange permission error on a folder that has user permissions.  The makefile looks like this:

```
PID      = /tmp/nodemon-golang-project.pid
TMPL_FILES = $(shell find . -type f -name '*.tmpl') 
GO_FILES =  $(shell find . -type f -name '*.go')
CMD_FILES = $(shell find ./cmd -type f -name '*.go')
SASS_FILES = $(shell find ./scss -type f -name '*.scss')
APP      = ./app
CSS      = ./static/css/style.css

serve: restart
    @fswatch -o . | xargs -n1 -I{}  make restart || make kill

kill:
    @kill `cat $(PID)` || true

before:
    @echo "\nRESTARTED ..."


$(APP): $(GO_FILES) $(TMPL_FILES)
    echo $(GO_FILES)
    @go build -o $@ $(CMD_FILES)

$(CSS): $(SASS_FILES)
    @echo Generating CSS
    @rm static/css/style.css
    @sh -c sass scss/styles.scss static/css/style.css

restart: kill before $(APP) $(CSS)
    @$(APP) & echo $$! > $(PID)
    @echo Try css
    @$(CSS)

.PHONY: serve restart kill before scss
```

I get the error when this runs:

```sh
$ gmake serve

RESTARTED ...
Try css
gmake: ./static/css/style.css: Permission denied
gmake: *** [Makefile:32: restart] Error 127
```

I'm trying to figure out why I'd get a permission error. All of the directories are under the normal user, and gmake is running under that same user. All of the directories involved as well, and all the directories are writable and executable.

Why would gmake have a problem with a normal file with normal permissions? Am I doing something wrong with the Makefile that would cause this kind of error?

Comment: Why are you trying to execute a CSS file?

Comment: If I am, I'm not intending to. What bit of my syntax causes that?

Comment: My intention is to cause the static/css/style.css file to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

First rule of debugging makefiles is, *never* add `@` to your makefile until it's fully working.  You're just hiding all the critical information from yourself.  Even after it's fully working I recommend not adding `@`.

Second, I don't know why you're adding `sh -c` to this rule; you're already in a shell, why start another one?

```
@sh -c sass scss/styles.scss static/css/style.css
```

However none of the above are your problem.  Your problem is this:

```
CSS      = ./static/css/style.css
    ....
restart: kill before $(APP) $(CSS)
        @$(APP) & echo $$! > $(PID)
        @echo Try css
        @$(CSS)
```

Note this last line; `CSS` expands to `./static/css/style.css` so that file is invoked as a program, but it doesn't have executable bits set, so the invocation fails.

Comment: Yeah, was not my intention to try to execute it. Was my intention to get that file conditionally rebuilt from %.scss files via the sass executable.  As for "sh -c".  Desperation, mainly :-) I was trying to figure out why I was getting the error.

Comment: Well, I don't understand at all what you're trying to do, but you can't "run" a .css file.  Everything in a make recipe (the part indented with TAB) must be a shell script: something you'd type at your shell prompt.  The failure is happening in a completely different rule than the one where the `sh -c` occurs (remove the `@` everywhere!) so that won't help anything.

Comment: I get that. I don't necessarily get Makefile syntax.  So, I get your point. And building CSS files out of SCSS files isn't rocket science. Is that *so* unclear?

Comment: Makefile syntax is simple; here is an intro: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html.  Your one-sentence statement of what you want to do is clear.  What's not clear is what your makefile is trying to do.

Comment: @TorenwareNetworks, perhaps what you're looking for is simply to remove the last two lines of the recipe for target `restart`.  Having a rule for building target `$(CSS)` and expressing `$(CSS)` as a prerequisite of `restart` are jointly sufficient to get `$(CSS)` to be rebuilt, if needed, when the `restart` target is built.  When I say "when", though, I mean before the recipe for `restart` is executed, which might be different timing than you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It seems they are trying to start some kind of server and run it in the background, presumably to build the CSS.  But this would have to be done before the CSS file is created, but here that won't happen because CSS is a prerequisite of the target who's recipe starts the server.  However, I don't really want to spend time writing a correct version without understanding what the requirements actually are, so I'll wait for that rather than guess.